How to resume a docker-compose up that failed on its last steps?
I'm running a docker-compose up that is running smoothly, but takes time to do so, for a while:
 => [build_base  5/13] RUN apt-get update &&  apt-get install -y python3-pip                                                                                                   4.5s
 => [build_base  6/13] RUN pip install conan --break-system-packages                                                                                                           5.8s
 => [build_base  7/13] RUN apt remove cmake -y                                                                                                                                 1.0s
 => [build_base  8/13] RUN pip install cmake --upgrade --break-system-packages                                                                                                 5.7s
 => [build_base  9/13] RUN conan profile detect --force                                                                                                                        0.6s
 => [build_base 10/13] RUN conan install . -of=build -b=missing -s compiler.cppstd=gnu17                                                                                    1083.9s

but alas, at step [build_base 12/13] there's a mistake in the task provided and I have to do some tries to attempt correcting it.
The problem is that, for each attempt, I am running a docker-compose up command again, and it restarts everything from the beginning: [build_base 1/13]
How may I ask docker-compose up to resume on [build_base 12/13] task, considering the others steps being done?
